# java- Why am I getting "class is not abstract and does not override abstract method" when creating my ATM with gui?

Tags: java, swing

Making an ATM with options to withdraw and deposit. I'm including the shortened version of the code, I do have buttons for the other ATM features but omitted it to post. I also omitted the parts with my dimensions/formatting.

```
public class ATM extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   private JButton withdraw1, withdraw2, deposit;
   private JLabel displayInput, instructions; 
   private JPanel buttonPanel; 



public  ATM() {
   withdraw1 = new JButton("Withdraw $20");
   withdraw1.addActionListener(this);
   withdraw2 = new JButton("Withdraw $40");
   withdraw2.addActionListener(this);
   deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
   deposit.addActionListener(this);

}
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonClicked) {
```

I then have all my code for what to do when each button is clicked. Here is the error I am getting:

ATM.java:6: error: ATM is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class ATM extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
       ^
How can I fix this error?

Comment: You `ATM` class does not implement the requirements of the `ActionListener` contract (you have your `ButtonListener` doing it).  Have a look at [Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the abstract method: `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`

Whenever a class `implements` an interface, it must provide an implementation for all the methods in the interface.

Another option would be to remove the "`implements ActionListener`" from your `ATM` class.

Comment: I'm a little confused... so would it be: abstract actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonClicked) ?

Comment: @xson, you were given a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Write an ActionListener` (in the comments to your queston). So read the tutorial for a working example.

Comment: You should either remove the "implements ActionListener" from your ATM class, or otherwise implement that method (actually you need to write the method code).